# how to prevent cutting the background?

Tags: css, background

I set background image in #section-content, background is repeat-x, and background color in #section-footer. Problem is that backgrounds are cut by the amount of space that is first seen.

Is there any way to fix this?

There is image with problem, you can see that footer background color is cut off when is resolution or window small and I scroll right...

[Problem image](http://www.dodaj.rs/f/o/FM/4nx2Rk3J/problem.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide source code or context for your problem? It's hard to solve when it's this vague

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. Make a jsFiddle or show us some code/screen shots.

Comment: I working in CMS and its little complicated to provide source code, I edit my question and you can see image with problem...

Comment: This isn't a background issue, it's an overflow issues or width of div issue. Code is needed to resolve this, or the website url, ptrefereably

Comment: @j08691 that don't helps...

Comment: the same problem exists on Stack Overflow site, try to reduce browser window size and look at footer, background is cut off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define min-width to the footer. Consider your **main page wrapper has width: 980px;** then assign **min-width: 980px; to the footer** element. When you resize the browser window, your footer knows that he has to repeat the background to the specified min-width even when your page gets horizontal scroll.

Comment: @mixerowsky BTW - even StackOverflow has the same issue with it's footer background color. Resize until it gets horizontal scroll and see :)

Answer (score 0):

my html structure looks like this

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="section-header">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="section-content">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="section-footer">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

so I add to css

```
#page {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 1180px; /* it fits on my site */
}
```

and problem is solved...